# German MO combinatorics problem 1995

Tags: combinatorics, contest-math, binomial-coefficients

I found this old German MO problem in a book but no answer is given.
Here is the problem : Prove that for all integers $k$ and $n$ with $1\le k\le 2n$ :
$$\binom{2n+1}{k-1}+\binom{2n+1}{k+1}\ge 2\cdot \frac{n+1}{n+2}\cdot \binom{2n +1}{k}$$
Does anyone know how to solve it or where could i find the answer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to clarify user 10354138 answer beacause there might be a small mistake:

$$\frac{k}{2n-k+2}+\frac{2n-k+1}{k+1}\ge 2\cdot \frac{n+1}{n+2}$$
$$\iff \frac{k}{2n-k+2}+\frac{2n-k+1}{k+1}-\frac{2(n+1)}{n+2}\ge0$$
$$\iff \frac{k(k+1)(n+2)+(n+2)(2n-k+1)(2n-k+2)-2(n+1)(2n-k+ 2)(k+1)}{(2n-k+2)(k+1)(n+2)}\ge0$$

As from the statement $2n\ge k\ge1$, we know that the denominator is strictly positive. It remains to show that the numerator is positive:
$$ k^2n+2k^2+kn+2k+(2n^2-kn+5n-2k+2)(2n-k+2)-(2nk+2n+2k+2)(2n-k+2) \ge0$$
$$\iff 4n^3+10n^2-8kn^2+6n-16kn+4k^2n+6k^2-6k\ge0$$
$$\iff 2(n-k)(2n+3)(n-k+1)\ge0$$

Answer (score 4):

If we add $2{2n+1\choose k}$ to both sides we get
$${2n+3\choose k+1}\geq\frac{4n+6}{n+2}{2n+1\choose k}$$
and
$$(n+1)(n+2)\ge(k+1)(2n-k+2)$$
and
$$(n-k)^2\geq k-n$$
which is true for all integers.

Answer (score 2):

Dividing by $\binom{2n+1}{k}$, it suffices to prove
$$
\frac{k}{2n-k+2}+\frac{2n-k+1}{k+1}\geq2\cdot\frac{n+1}{n+2}.
$$

Transfer everything to LHS and putting everything under same denominators, this is equivalent to
$$
\frac{2(2n+3)(n-k)(n+1-k)}{(k+1)(2n+2-k)(n+2)}\geq 0.
$$
For integers $n,k$ satisfying $1\leq k\leq 2n$, the denominator is clearly positive, and the numerator is positive for $k\neq n,n+1$ where it is $0$, as desired.